# Grouping conditions with parentheses not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean-logic, operator-precedence

I am trying to use an SQL query in Postgres that looks like this:

```
UPDATE gamebet 
SET points = 15 
WHERE game = 8 
  AND "scoreT1" > "scoreT2" 
  AND "scoreT1" - "scoreT2" != 1 
  AND ("scoreT1" != 1 AND "scoreT2" != 0)
```

It should update the scores of some bets where scoreT1 is bigger than scoreT2, but there are some rows that should not be updated. And that is when scoreT1 - scoreT2 = 1 And if both scoreT1 = 1 and scoreT2 = 0, but it should only apply if both of these conditions are met. And somehow the parenthesis are not applied. Since e.g. this record is not modified:

```
scoreT1 = 3
scoreT2 = 0
```

This record should be updated, but since one of the conditions is `scoreT2 != 0` it is not updated. How can I group the last conditions that they need to be met together?

Comment: Your record fails the test `scoreT2 != 0`.  Of course it is not modified.

Comment: *Always* include the exact table definition with a question like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as NULL values are not ruled out, your description must be translated to something like this:

```
UPDATE gamebet 
SET    points = 15 
WHERE  game = 8 
AND   "scoreT1" > "scoreT2" 
AND  ("scoreT1" = "scoreT2" + 1 AND "scoreT1" = 1) IS NOT TRUE;
```

The additional condition `"scoreT2" = 0` follows logically from the first two and is redundant.

If `"scoreT1"` and `"scoreT2"` are defined **`NOT NULL`**, you can further simplify:

```
...
AND   NOT ("scoreT1" = "scoreT2" + 1 AND "scoreT1" = 1)
```

Or with inverted logic:

```
...
AND   ("scoreT1" <> "scoreT2" + 1 OR "scoreT1" <> 1)
```

Read about [Logical Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-logical.html#), [Comparison Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html) and [Operator Precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) in the manual.

And if `points` can already *be* 15, it pays to add another predicate to avoid empty updates:

```
AND points IS DISTINCT FROM 15
```

Or, with NULL values ruled out:

```
AND points <> 15
```

Details:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Answer (score 0):

From your description you want

```
 NOT("scoreT1" - "scoreT2" == 1 OR ("scoreT1" == 1 AND "scoreT2" == 0))
```

Which logically would be

```
 "scoreT1" - "scoreT2" != 1 AND ("scoreT1" != 1 OR "scoreT2" != 0)
```

When you commute a NOT operator into a compound comparison you flip `AND`s to `OR`s and vice-versa.